# OnCollisionEnter not firing in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this has been asked many times but I have checked as many forums as I can. Here is everything I'm doing:

I have a cube (that in this case is serving as the floor) with the following properties

[image: Cube Properties]

and I have a "Runner" that is just a cube with the following properties

[image: Runner Properties]

I froze the z position and rotations because this is a side-scroller.

The `onCollisionEnter` method for the "Runner" that you can see is attached to the "Runner" object is as follows:

```
    void onCollisionEnter(){
    print("Collision Detected");
}
```

And when I run it, I get bupkis. So. Help please? It seems so simple but I am clearly messing something up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not

```
void onCollisionEnter()
```

but [as stated in the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html)

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
```

So the method is written in full CamelCase and has an argument.